# Matlab: auto axis range when you have two plots in the same figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I use the following:

```
semilogy(x,P1);
hold on
semilogy(x,P2);    
hold off
axis([-inf,inf,0.0001,1])
```

No matter where I place the 'axis' command, it always give me a range suitable for P1, but not P2. Is there anything that can be done to have the auto ranging functionality to take both plots into account?

Comment: What are the ranges of your `P1` and `P2` data? What do you mean by not suitable? If your `P2` data exceeds 1, for instance, the `axis` command here will never be suitable, since you need to change the `YMAX` value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the YLim property of your current axes, and set it to the minimal/maximal value between P1 and P2:

```
set(gca,'YLim',[min(P1,P2) max(P1,P2)]);
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: P1 and P2 are vectors, so you cannot use min(P1,P2); it doesn't work. What I simply want is to use the normal auto axis function but with two plots in the graph instead of just one.

Comment: well you can use min(P1,P2) with vectors; it will output the minimal value between the 2 vectors so your axis would fit both of them for sure.